# # Bits required for logical/physical address (paging)?

Tags: memory-management, paging, memory-address

Not sure if this is legal because it's homework, but oops:

```
Consider a logical address space of 256 pages with a 4-KB page size, mapped onto a physical memory of 64 frames. 

a. How many bits are required in the logical address? 

b. How many bits are required in the physical address?
```

For logical address my guess is 20bits (8 to represent 256 pages; 12 to represent 4096 offset) HOWEVER, I noticed that they're asking for **bits** rather than **bytes**; does this mean that I'd actually need 12*8 extra bits to account for the offset...? Then again, each bit in an address should probably map to the location of a byte, so probably not.

Is the physical address just however many bits it takes to represent 64 * 4096 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the memory is byte addressable, then,

> # bits in logical address = 20 bits
>
> # bits in physical address = 18 bits

**Explanation**
There is something called addressable unit for a memory. This is the smallest individual measurement by which you can access the memory.

i,e if your memory is of 32 Bytes and addressable unit is Byte, then you need 5 bits to represent each of the memory unit (1 byte here). Because we have 32 such units and log(32)<sub>2</sub> = 5

if your memory is of 32 Bytes and addressable unit is bit, then you need 8 bits to represent each of the memory unit (1 bit here). Because we have 32*8 such units and log(256)<sub>2</sub> = 8

Since in your question the addressable unit is not mentioned, we can consider it as byte addressable(Most common one)

Comment: Yep, makes the most sense; I just confused myself with the whole bit-byte thing because I never thought about it and I don't really know what I'm doing...